# django-registration oddity

Tags: django, registration, django-registration

So I downloaded the app with easy_install and it worked.  I can import registration.

BUT the code installed doesn't match the source code for the project, as seen in github.  For example, I'm missing the modules backends.urls and tests.  I'm also missing key files like auth_urls. Without these modules, the registration app is failing on me.

Could this be related to my directory structure?

My Ubuntu distribution has placed all my python files in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/

as opposed to /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/

Otherwise, I'm stumped here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `easy_install` version was really out of date last time I tried.

You'll need to either download the source and run `python setup.py install` from the extracted directory or checkout from the Git repo and run the same command.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that easy_install installing 0.7 version. But in a github you can see 0.8 alpha